# Is there a way to describe that parameters are not mutated through a forwarding reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, perfect-forwarding, forwarding-reference

Among the many benefits of const qualification is to make an API more understandable, example:

```
template<typename T> int function1(T const& in);
// clearly, the input won’t change through function1
```

With the introduction of rvalue references, one can benefit from perfect forwarding but often const qualifiers are removed, example:

```
template<typename T> int function2(T&& in);
// can explicitly forward the input if it's an rvalue
```

Apart from documentation, is there a good way to describe that function2 won’t change its input?

Comment: If you're just forwarding the parameters to someone else, what do you care what is or is not `const`? You let them deal with it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> ```
> template<typename T> int function2(T&& in);
> // can explicitly forward the input if it's an rvalue
> ```
>
> Apart from documentation, is there a good way to describe that
>   function2 won’t change its input?

Yes.  Stick with the C++03 solution:

```
template<typename T> int function1(T const& in);
// clearly, the input won’t change through function1
```

The benefits of perfect forwarding are that you don't want to assume if something is `const` or non-`const`, lvalue or rvalue.  If you want to enforce that something is not modified (i.e. that it is `const`), then explicitly say so by adding `const`.

You could do this:

```
template<typename T> int function1(T const&& in);
// clearly, the input won’t change through function1
```

However everyone who read your code would wonder why you've used rvalue references.  And `function1` would cease to accept lvalues.  Just use `const &` instead and everyone will understand.  It is a simple and well understood idiom.

You don't want to perfectly forward.  You want to enforce immutability.

Answer (score 9):

You could say this:

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<immutable<T>::value, int>::type
function(T && in)
{
   // ...
}
```

where you have something like:

```
template <typename T> struct immutable
: std::integral_constant<bool, !std::is_reference<T>::value> {};

template <typename U> struct immutable<U const &>
: std::true_type {};
```

This way, the template will only be usable if the universal reference is either a const-reference (so `T = U const &`) or an rvalue-reference (so `T` is not a reference).

---

That said, if the argument is not going to be changed, you could just use `T const &` and be done with it, since there's nothing to be gained from binding mutably to temporary values.