# (rvalue reference) VS (const lvalue reference) as function parameters in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

Can someone explain when rvalue references are preferred over const lvalue references when working as function parameters?

**Background**:
I was trying to pass a const pointer into a function. Since I have to consider the cases in which a local pointer is passed in and in which a temporary is passed in (say from a function call return), I have two choices: the parameter could either be declared as:

```
void foo(T const* const&); //const lvalue ref to const ptr
```

or

```
void foo(T const* &&); //rvalue ref to const ptr
```

But this rvalue reference cannot be bound to a local variable (which is of lvalue type. But I did remember Scott Meyers coined the term "universal reference" to refer to rvalue reference. This confuses me more.) So my question is, since the first declaration could deal with both cases, when would the second one using rvalue reference be preferred?

**Note**: In the first approach, the other forms

```
void foo(const const T* &); 
void foo(const T* const&);
```

didn't work. I guess the reason is that in the latter two I was not consistent in the place where the const qualifiers are put into (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17005423/c-rvalue-reference-and-const-qualifier might help, but your question is a bit confusing. You seem to be mixing freely const pointer and pointer to const. If you don't need to perfectly forward or move, rvalue refs aren't really useful.

Comment: "universal references" are only when an rvalue reference is used with a template.

Answer (score 8):

It is very rarely a good idea to pass a pointer by `const &`: at best it takes the same overhead, at worst it causes extremely complex pointer reseating logic to surprise readers of your code.

Take pointers by value -- `T const*` -- and things are more sane.

References to non-pointer values make more sense.

Universal references is a technique using rvalue and lvalue references in a type deduction context.  It basically only applies when you have a type `T&&` being deduced from an expression -- in that context `T` can be `X`, `X&` or `X const&` (or other cv variants).

If `T` is `X&` or `X const&`, the rvalue reference to the lvalue reference collapses into a lvalue reference.  It is an example of the standard committee being clever, and it allows `auto&&x=` based universal reference variables, and perfect forwarding code to be easy to write.

Comment: I agree that taking a pointer by const-reference isn't very useful (as stated in my answer). But can you explain the "extremely complex pointer reseating logic"?

Comment: @jogojapan suppose the referred to pointer is changed at some point in the middle of the function: it is realseated.  Handling that possibility requires reexamining your assumptions about the pointer in every line of the function with non-local code executed.  Only if that happens are the two different (or if the ref persists after the function call)

Comment: I don't understand the second part of your comment, but regardig the first part: We are talking about a constant pointer (or constant pointer reference). How can that be reseated?

Comment: Thanks! I learned a lot from both your and @jogojapan 's answers.

Comment: @jogojapan because a `const&` to a pointer need not be the only way to access that pointer.  A `const&` only means access through this variable cannot modify it.

Answer (score 3):

*Remark:* I wrote this answer under the assumption that `T` in your question represents some actual data type -- I've chosen `int` in my examples below.

> Background: I was trying to pass a const pointer into a function. [...] I have to consider the cases in which a local pointer is passed in and in which a temporary is passed in (say from a function call return)

You didn't say what you mean by "const pointer". I will first assume you mean a pointer that is itself constant (i.e. the address to which it points cannot be changed).

According to your description, there are basically two ways you get such a pointer:

```
// Case 1 (what you call a local pointer -- this should be inside some
//         function body):
int *const p = 0;

// Case 2, a function that returns a pointer; this is your rvalue case
// in contexts where f() is called and its return value used as a temporary:
int *f()
{ return 0; }

// Note: The temporary returned by this function isn't, strictly speaking,
//       constant. It could be modified as long as it is alive. But from
//       your description I take it that you have no intentions of doing so
//       and/or regard temporaries as generally constant.
```

Now you can define a function that accepts these two cases as follows:

```
void g(int *const &arg)
{ }
```

You can apply this as `g(p);` to a constant, local pointer such as `p` defined earlier, as well as to a temporary `g(f());`. (You could, thirdly, apply it to a non-const local pointer as well, because going from non-const lvalue to const lvalue is never a problem.)

This function `g` has a function argument `arg` which is defined as a constant, lvalue reference to an `int`-pointer. It can bind to a constant (or indeed non-constant) local pointer (such as `p`) as well as a temporary, because constant lvalue references, unlike non-constant lvalue references, can do that.

*Remark:* It's not clear to me why, in this case, you need the function argument to be a reference at all. You could simply declare `void g(int *const arg)` (no ampersand) and do without a reference. Reasons include a) You cannot modify it anyway; b) In all real-world implementations, the reference will take just as much (or as little) space as the pointer itself, so there is no point in avoiding a copy.

Anyway. If you want you can also define a second version of `g` specifically for rvalue references:

```
void g(int *&& arg)
{ }
```

This can *only* be applied to the temporary, not to the local pointer, because the function argument is defined as an rvalue reference, which can bind to temporaries, but not to lvalues.

However, if by "const pointer" you actually mean a pointer-to-const, i.e. a pointer that can be changed to different addresses, but does not have the power to modify the value stored at those addresses, the declarations are a bit different. The keyword `const` must then be put before the asterisk, and for better clarity best before the type specifier `int`:

```
// Declare local pointer-to-const:
const int *p = 0;

// Function that returns a pointer-to-const:
const int *f()
{ return 0; }
```

A function that can accept these two would then be declared as:

```
void g(const int *const &arg)
{ }
```

The first `const` means we are talking about pointers-to-const, and the second `const` ensures we have a constant lvalue-reference, which can bind to both rvalues and lvalues. Note that this function can not modify what `arg` points to, because `arg` is declared as a constant lvalue reference. In the case where `arg` binds to the temporary, that is probably what we want anyway (as stated above). But in the case where the function is called as `g(p);`, we might actually want to modify the local pointer `p` from within `g`. If you want `g` to have this power, you need to define two versions of it:

```
void g(const int *&& arg)
{ /* Can bind to temporaries, but not modify them. */ }

void g(const int *& arg)
{ /* Can bind to local variables and modify what they point at */ }
```

---

**Remark 1:** Your original declaration `const int *const &const` is useless (and not even accepted by GCC). It would mean a "constant reference to a constant pointer to constant int", but since a reference to a constant pointer is implicitly itself a const-reference, the final `const` is superfluous (and not provided for by the Standard).

**Remark 2:** Universal references are not the same as rvalue references. Universal references are declared as `T &&arg` where `T` is a template parameter. Depending on what `T` refers to in each instantiation of the template, this may be an lvalue reference or an rvalue reference -- hence its "universal" character. This has nothing to do with your use case, anyway, though, since you are dealing with pointers `T *` here (even if we assume that `T` is a template parameter).

Comment: Nitpick: "The keyword const must then be put before the type specifier int:" - that's not entirely correct. It has to be before the `*`. `int const *` and `const int *` are the same type (pointer to const int). (The first version having the advantage that it can be read right-to-left.)

Comment: The rvalue lvalue applies to the pointer not the `T`, so it does not matter if `T` is a `template` parameter.

Comment: @Yakk That's also true -- although I will keep the remark about how I interpret `T` for better clarity.

Comment: Thank you very much, @jogojapan, for such a detailed explanation. I now understand the pointer stuff better. Before I was taking pointer as normal object, and was trying to avoid copy. But now I understand that's a bad idea, not good at the least. BTW, I was in deed trying to do some template work and by const ptr I mean low level constant-ness.

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to differentiate between a temporary pointer and an lvalue pointer. That looks to me like something that's bound to fail rather sooner than later.

Universal Refs only apply in template functions like

```
 template<class T> void foo(T && fwdref);
```

Note that a "universal ref" is *not* the same as an rvalue ref.